# How to prove by mathematical induction that $a_n > 5$ for every positive integer $n$.

Tags: proof-writing, induction

The sequence $a_1 , a_2 , a_3\dots$ is such that $a_1 > 5$ and $a_{n+1} = \frac{4a_n}{5} + \frac{5}{a_n}$ for every positive integer $n$. How to prove by mathematical induction that $a_n > 5$ for every positive integer $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $a_n>5$, we can assume that $a_n=5+x$, where $x>0$.

Therefore

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{4(5+x)}5+\frac{5}{5+x}=5+\left(\frac{4x}5-\frac{x}{5+x}\right)$$

Now we will prove that $\frac{4x}5-\frac{x}{5+x}>0$ for all $x>0$.

$\frac{4x}5-\frac{x}{5+x}>0\iff4x(5+x)-5x>0\iff4x^2+15x>0$

which is apparently true for $x>0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$a_{n+1} = \frac{4a_n}{5} + \frac{5}{a_n}\\$$
$$ \space x=\frac{a_n}{5}\to $$ if we solve $$4x+\frac 1x >5\\
x>0 \to \times x\\4x^2-5x+1>0\\(x-1)(4x-1)>0\\x \not\in [\frac14,1] or \\x>1\cup x<\frac14 $$so it suffice $$x>1$$ it means $$\frac{a_n}{5}>1\to a_n>5$$